# How do you format addresses for the deploy transaction of a contract?

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

Why does my deploy transaction run into a runtime error when the constructor uses an address parameter but not contracts with 0 parameters or non-address datatypes?

I run into this error
[image: runtime error]

when I try to run the below code.
Even if I take out web3.utils.toHex() I still get the same error.
In the comments you can see that I've noted that other argument types work. What special needs to happen to addresses to format them correctly?

```
fs = require("fs")

const web3 = new (require("web3"))('HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545')
console.log("web3")

let accounts = [];
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(result){
    accounts = result
    console.log(accounts)
})

deployContract('false-resolve.sol', "DummyToken",[]).then(function(result){
    //THIS WORKS
    //deployContract('false-resolve.sol', "DummyToken",[])

    //THIS WORKS
    //deployContract('UintConstructor.sol', "UintConstructor", [ 1 ] ).then(function(r){
    //  console.log("UintConstructor._address", r._address) 
    //})

    deployContract('orocl.sol', "Oracle", [ web3.utils.toHex("0x786c35Ae953f94fc4Ffd31Edd0388d50fCF5Bb70") ] ).then(function(r){
        console.log("r._address", r._address)
    })
})
function deployContract(CONTRACT_FILE, contractName, args){
    const content = fs.readFileSync(CONTRACT_FILE).toString()
    const input = {
      language: 'Solidity',
      sources: {
        [CONTRACT_FILE]: {
          content: content
        }
      },
      settings: {
        outputSelection: {
          '*': {
            '*': ['*']
          }
        }
      }
    }

    var compiled = solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))
    var output = JSON.parse(compiled)
    var abi = output.contracts[CONTRACT_FILE][contractName].abi
    var bytecode = output.contracts[CONTRACT_FILE][contractName].evm.bytecode.object.toString()
    var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi)

    var contractTx = contract.deploy({data: "0x"+bytecode, arguments: args});
    return contractTx.send({from: '0x786c35Ae953f94fc4Ffd31Edd0388d50fCF5Bb70', gas: 4700000})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now `bytecode` isn't actually hex formatted data, you have it as a string with `0x` in front of it.

You probably want to pass bytecode data directly:

```
...

var bytecode = output.contracts[CONTRACT_FILE[contractName].evm.bytecode;

...

var contractTx = contract.deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: args});
```

Referencing this [Ethereum.SE question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71637/error-the-data-field-must-be-hex-encoded-data).

Comment: How do you know it's not hex formatted? It works with or without the 0x in front of it when there are no address parameters in the constructor. It's only when I introduce the address parameter that it throws the error. The bytecode of the contract isn't the transaction data, because the transaction data must include the arguments used in the constructor.

Comment: This may have something to do with a library my contract is dependent on. I believe the library needs to be deployed first.  I can get around that. Thanks for your help

Comment: my problem came down to the fact that I had a library that my contract was referencing but I hadn't deployed the library first.